# Dynamically generated drop down list using @html.dropdownlistfor helper in mvc 4 loosing selection of items on page post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am very new in MVC, however i am able to display and get proper value at Controller from dynamically generated DropdownList using @html.dropdownlistfor helper (with Razor View Engine), but getting problem to return view with selected dropdownlist items on post back.

Following my Code:

**Model:**

```
    public class CollectionViewModel 
    {
    public List<TempAccount> temp { get; set; } // for Prepare UI
    public List<Trn_Loans> colls { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Date")]
    public DateTime TrnDate { get; set; }

    public int TrnTypesId { get; set; }
    public string expectedReceiveableAmount { get; set; }
    public int ReqRouteNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**View:**

```
         @model SFSW.ViewModels.CollectionViewModel

         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.colls[i].Executive1Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ExecutiveDDN1, String.Empty)
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

 public ActionResult Create(CollectionViewModel modelCollection)
  {
 ....on ModelState.false

 ViewBag.ExecutiveDDN1 = new SelectList(db.ddl_VerifiedBy, "ddl_VerifiedById", "Name", String.Empty);
  return View(modelCollection);
  }
```

Proper ID in @Model.colls[i].Executive1Id is coming upto postback view but dropdownlist itmes not selects from this this ID.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you indexing the dropdown? Are you using a for loop that you haven't shown?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Please Refer the lambda expression in my View [ @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.colls[i].Executive1Id ], it is itself carrying the required value, hence there is no further loop required.

Comment: Sorry, yes the lambda expression in my View itself in a loop, i.e. @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.colls.Count; i++) {.. // here is the lambda expression..}

Comment: The value of the dropdownList will bind to colls.Executive1Id, you said it is happening. I'm not sure what the question is

Comment: If you expect the entire Select List to come back that won't happen, the only thing that will return from the View will be the selected dropdown value

Comment: On page post back i am loosing selection of items from this dynamically generated dropdownlists, for static dropdownlist i am getting the selection i am expecting the same behavior here.

Comment: Are you losing the selection of items or are you losing the selected value, there is a difference. Only the selected value will be sent to the controller, **the other items inside the ddl will not**. The view doesn't know about all of the items in the dropdown only the selected value, that is why the dropdownlist SelectList will not go back to the controller. If you want to check ModelState and return to the view on an error, you will have to once again populate the SelectList fields before you do that.

Comment: No i am not loosing the selected values, selected values from all the dropdownlist is properly sends to controller as well as on model fail i am also getting all the values in the View but not getting the selected item as per model value, and obviously i am re-populating the dropdonlist from controller with a help of ViewBeg as you can see in my controller.